# Python: installing multiprocessing

Tags: python, module

I need to import the multiprocessing module in Python 2.5.

I've followed the instructions here exactly: http://code.google.com/p/python-multiprocessing/wiki/Install

make and make test run without errors. I've also edited $PYTHONPATH to include the directory where the package is installed.

But 'import multiprocessing' still says: "ImportError: no module named multiprocessing".

What am I doing wrong? Is there some step missing from these instructions? I haven't installed a Python module before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Navigate to the directory containing the package then type:

```
python setup.py install
```

This info was contained in the INSTALL.txt file.

http://code.google.com/p/python-multiprocessing/source/browse/trunk/INSTALL.txt

Answer (score -1):

perhaps you can try:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/processingdotpylibs/')
import processing
```